# Android - Create shortcut from adb

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I want to create a shortcut via adb for an application I'm developing.

I have looked in [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java#Launcher.infoFromShortcutIntent%28android.content.Context,android.content.Intent%29) to see how the intent Android is expecting to be formatted.
I also checked the [AM documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am) to try to create the intent required.

So far I got a lot of variations of the line below, but this one seems the most appropriate.

```
adb -d shell am broadcast \
-a com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT \
--es Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME "<shortcut-name>" \
--esn Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE \
<package-name>/.activity
```

I have left the `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE` null, since Android should search the package itself and use the app_icon defined there.

The command runs and produces

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT cmp=<package-name>/.activity (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

No shortcut is added to the main screen, and I suppose it has something to do with the switches of the command.

Anyone has come across anything like this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

-JK

Answer (score 2):

Taking the [default ICS Launcher as reference](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/packages/apps/Launcher2/src/com/android/launcher2/InstallShortcutReceiver.java), I see that the intent expects an extra which you are not sending: `android.intent.extra.shortcut.INTENT`. This intent is the one that will be used to start the application pointed by shortcut. Realize that the type expected for this extra is a parcelable . So far I know, `am` is not able to sent such data structure.

As a workaround, you can create a very simple application to send this broadcast.

First of all, add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />` to AndroidManifest.xml

Then, you could try in activity:

```
Intent shortcut = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
shortcut.setClassName("<package-name>", "<package-name>.activity");

Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "<shortcut-name>");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcut);

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: So we can't use any broadcast from command line and create a short cut on the HOME screen for any application?

Comment: @Ambi You don't as far as I know. But don't tweak with android since 2014, so my understanding may be outdated.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'll check if there are any other tweaks. By the way, is it possible to do an app that creates home screen short cuts for other applications?

Comment: @Ambi Yes,it is. The answer above shows how to do that.