# Create Website shortcut using ADB

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-broadcast

How do i add shortcut in home screen to open a particular website for example, `http://www.google.com` using adb shell script on device?

I am aware on how to do it using chrome's add to home screen option or third party apps which can create shortcuts, i am looking for creating shortcut over **ADB shell script**

I have also checked [Android - Create shortcut from adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043432/android-create-shortcut-from-adb) but i don't find relevant answer to create website shortcut to home screen over adb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Create shortcut from adb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043432/android-create-shortcut-from-adb)

Comment: @AlexP. i have already checked that answer and it just has syntax and no where helping me on getting to solution i need

Comment: also read my comments to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27793409/1778421